# How can I get an Eclipse installation that includes source code of its plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to look at the source of some core plugins of eclipse. I've downloaded [the Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliosr). To get the source of a plugin, I go to the "Plug-ins" view and right click on the plugin. Then, I select the "Import As" menu item and the "Project from a Repository..." submenu item to check out the plugin from its CVS repository. Checking out from the CVS is time consuming. So, I tried to [import the plugin as a source project or a binary project with linked content](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/import_wizards/import_plugins.htm). However, the imported project lacks source code because my Eclipse installation doesn't come with the source code of its plugins. I'm looking for a quicker way to access the source of eclipse plug-ins than checking them out from the CVS repository. So, I wonder how I can get an Eclipse installation that includes source code of its plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Eclipse Packages table](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages), the distro you downloaded ([RCP](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliosr)) does include the Eclipse main plugin sources.

If that is not enough, you have other ways illustrated in this [Eclipse Code Access Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html), but it will involve at some point CVS or Git access.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the specific Eclipse plugin update site. Most of the plugins in Eclipse provide SDK feature which also include the source code of the plugins.

For example if you want the code for Eclipse core, use update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6. It has Eclipse Platform SDK and Eclipse SDK. For Web Tools the update site is : http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios